# Autorestart MongoDB on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, systemd, systemctl

I have mongodb set to autoload in systemctl. But when I make too many requests to it, it crashes with the mark `failed`. how can I make autorestart mongodb so that even after an error it starts up and works again, now I have to manually prescribe `systemctl start mongod`

Comment: Can you paste your mongodb unit file ? Looks like you're missing some `Restart=always` in your `[Service]` section.

Comment: @papey where can i find this config file?

Comment: Probably in `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` if not try `systemctl cat mongod` and you should see the path.

Comment: @papey thx, i find this file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @papey say, there is need to check `Restart=always` field in this file `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service`